# .htaccess inherit "require user" in subfolders and add specific user

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have multiple interfaces to manage different sections of our website.

Every user is responsible of his own section, and should just have access to the interface of his section.
some users like Webmaster, Big Boss and website content manager (let call them VIP) must have global access to all the interfaces.

To manage access to each section, I use a .htaccess file in the root folder of each section, with specific users for each one. But in order to geive access to all sections to VIP, I have to write theire names in all the .htaccess files.. this causes me a lot of work when one of them changes or if I have to create a new global access to some new manager.

is there any way for me to put the global access informations in one .htaccess file in the root folder (which contains all the sections as sub folders) and inherit this in the subfolders while adding specific users for each subfolder?

I hope I was clear.. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to implement HTTP Basic Authentication (that's what you are doing with the `.htaccess` file right now) in PHP.

There is [a tutorial on HTTP Basic Authentication](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) on the PHP website.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer... but this would take a lot of time to do...  because I will gave to change in the php code of all my page..
I hope there is much simpler way